# Baseline Profiles - Metrics are not consistent

Tags: android, performance, baseline-profile, macrobenchmark

I'm implementing the Baseline profile in an app and when I run my macrobenchmark tests, the results are not consistent. Not always the results are optimized using the baselineprofile.txt.

I'm running the macrobenchmark test in an emulator with this configuration:

- Pixel 6
- Android 11.0 (API 30) x86_64 (Google APIs)
- 6144MB Internal Storage
- 1536GB RAM

My baselineprofile.txt file has a size of 7MB.

And my results are, for example:

```
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupNoCompilation[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 344.4,   median 424.3,   max 466.6
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupFullCompilation[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 355.0,   median 379.1,   max 690.1
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialBaseline[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 211.4,   median 319.0,   max 363.3
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialNoBaseline[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 301.1,   median 396.0,   max 479.3
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4

HomeStartupBenchmark_startupNoCompilation[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 285.1,   median 385.5,   max 435.4
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupFullCompilation[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 238.1,   median 331.8,   max 360.9
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialBaseline[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 263.4,   median 338.9,   max 393.4
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialNoBaseline[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 281.2,   median 373.1,   max 434.0
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4

HomeStartupBenchmark_startupNoCompilation[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 243.8,   median 252.2,   max 280.8
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeFeedStartupBenchmark_startupFullCompilation[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 219.2,   median 245.9,   max 272.7
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialBaseline[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 175.4,   median 284.6,   max 611.3
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialNoBaseline[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 253.0,   median 305.9,   max 310.7
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
```

In this run, the startupPartialBaseline result is better than startupPartialNoBaseline in all compilations modes (COLD, WARM and HOT), and it's ok.

But in a second run I got:

```
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupNoCompilation[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min   510.6,   median   702.0,   max 1,456.0
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupFullCompilation[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 323.5,   median 425.0,   max 650.1
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialBaseline[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min   277.8,   median   385.7,   max 1,416.7
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialNoBaseline[mode=COLD]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 249.4,   median 319.4,   max 437.9
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4

HomeStartupBenchmark_startupNoCompilation[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 217.9,   median 301.1,   max 340.5
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupFullCompilation[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 197.0,   median 269.0,   max 337.6
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialBaseline[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 214.6,   median 281.5,   max 323.3
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeFeedStartupBenchmark_startupPartialNoBaseline[mode=WARM]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 246.4,   median 358.8,   max 418.0
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4

HomeStartupBenchmark_startupNoCompilation[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 254.1,   median 449.9,   max 473.9
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupFullCompilation[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min   391.3,   median   823.7,   max 1,448.4
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialBaseline[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 206.1,   median 235.2,   max 335.4
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
HomeStartupBenchmark_startupPartialNoBaseline[mode=HOT]
timeToInitialDisplayMs   min 237.8,   median 246.8,   max 275.0
Traces: Iteration 0 1 2 3 4
```

But here the COLD compilation using the baseline profile has a worst performance than not using the baselineprofile.

Comment: Same. In my case the none compilation mode was faster than partial compilation mode. Did you happen to know what was the problem for you ?

Comment: How are you testing NoBaseline? AFAIK there is no way to do this except remove the profile file.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly make sure to use the latest AGP (7.3.0-rc01), macrobenchmark (1.2.0-alpha03), and profileinstaller (1.2.0).

The device you're using for benchmarking can be under different load at different times.
I'd recommend to also **increase the amount of iterations** to give you more consistent results.
For the samples we chose 5 iterations as a trade off between speed and somehow accurate results.
As the milage for you app might vary, play with different numbers to see what works for you. 10 runs can provide more accurate results but will take more time to execute.

Comment: Still the none compilation mode is faster. This is very strange.

Comment: @FarazAhmed Got the similar results, None compilation mode for Cold start is faster than with full baseline profile. You found anything ?